# Polymer & google cloud endpoints Go backend

Tags: google-app-engine, polymer, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm trying to get my google cloud endpoint from polymer 1.0 all is set and working (backend and dispatcher on appengine), but the google-api-loader/google-client-loader (Tried both) refuses to acknowledge my endpoint, with google-api-loader nothing happens ready event never triggers, with google-client-loader it does but tries to get this url:

```
https://content.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/jobs/v1/rest?fields=rootUrl%2CservicePath%2Cresources%2Cparameters%2Cmethods&pp=0
```

Which has all google global apis, not the one from my endpoint.

Code:

```
<polymer-element name="job-service" attributes="jobs">                                                                                                                                                             
    <template>                                                                                                                                                                                                     
        <google-api-loader id="api" name="jobs" version="v1" appId="MyAppID" apiRoot="http://localhost:8082/_ah/api" root="http://localhost:8082/_ah/api">                                                                                                                                                               
        </google-api-loader>                                                                                                                                                                                    
    </template>                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    <script>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    Polymer({                                                                                                                                                                                         
        is: 'job-service',                                                                                                                                                                                         
        ready: function() {                                                                                                                                                                                        
            var setJobs = (function(data) {                                                                                                                                                                        
                this.jobs = data.result.jobs;                                                                                                                                                                      
            }).bind(this);                                                                                                                                                                                         

            this.$.api.addEventListener('google-api-load', (function() {                                                                                                                                           
                this.api = this.$.api.api;                                                                                                                                                                         
                this.api.getJobs().then(setJobs);                                                                                                                                                                  
            }).bind(this));                                                                                                                                                                                        
        },                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    });                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    </script>                                                                                                                                                                                                      
</polymer-element>
```

Tried updating google-apis to master nothing changed.

This is my bower.json:

```
{
  "name": "polymer-project",
  "dependencies": {
    "paper-header-panel": "PolymerElements/paper-header-panel#^1.0.0",
    "paper-item": "PolymerElements/paper-item#^1.0.0",
    "google-apis": "GoogleWebComponents/google-apis#master",
    "paper-icon-button": "PolymerElements/paper-icon-button#^1.0.0"
  }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some notes:

`google-client-loader` is the one you want

---

Until a new release you will have to depend on `#master` (as you are doing already) since the root/apiRoot fix hasn't been released yet .

---

With Polymer 1.0 camel-cased attributes become lowercase so passing in `apiRoot` would actually be an `apiroot`property. What you want is to set `api-root` and/or `app-id` instead (yeah I know that part is confusing..., see [Migration Guide](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/migration.html#property-name-to-attribute-name-mapping))

```
<google-client-loader
   id="api" name="jobs" version="v1"
   app-id="MyAppID" api-root="http://localhost:8082/_ah/api">
```

`app-id` won't be used though as long as `api-root` is set. Once you deploy this to your server you would have to remove `api-root`

---

Your code is still Polymer <0.6 and not Polymer 1.0 (unless you copied some old code).
It should look like this (see [Migration Guide](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/migration.html#registration)):

```
<dom-module id="job-service">
  <template>
    ...
  </template>
</dom-module>

<script>
  Polymer({
    is: 'job-service',
    ...
  )}
</script>
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you :), seems that I need to keep reading the migration guide...